# Local density of a deformed lattice to lowest order in displacement

Tags: condensed-matter, field-theory, density-operator, elasticity, dirac-delta-distributions

I am trying to understand the derivation from appendix A in the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9501087. The idea is to calculate the local density of a deformed lattice of a particle as a function of displacement field $\vec{u}$. If the lattice were perfect, then the particle density would be

$$\rho\left(\vec{r}\right)=\sum_{i}\boldsymbol{\delta}\left(\vec{r}-\vec{R_{i}}^{0}\right),$$

where $\vec{R_{i}}^{0}$ the position vectors of the underlying lattice. Now assume that particle changes positions the new position are given by

$$\vec{R}_{i}=\vec{R}_{i}^{0}+\vec{u}_{i}\left(\vec{R_{i}}^{0}\right),$$ where $\vec{u}_{i}\left(\vec{R_{i}}^{0}\right)$ is the displacement of the atom which was sitting in the lattice site labelled by $\vec{R_{i}}^{0}$. So the new density would be

$$\rho\left(\vec{r}\right)=\sum_{i}\boldsymbol{\delta}\left(\vec{r}-\vec{R_{i}}\right).$$ The result of appendix A in the above mentioned paper is that this density can be expanded as following

$$\rho\left(\vec{r}\right)\approx\rho_{0}-\rho_{0}\nabla.\vec{u}+\rho_{0}\sum_{\vec{K}\neq0}\exp\left(\dot{\iota}\vec{K}.\left(\vec{r}-\vec{u}\right)\right),$$

where $\rho_{0}$ is the average density, and $\vec{K}$ are the Brillouin zone (BZ) vectors of the undeformed lattice.

They arrive at this result by defining a continuous field  $\vec{\phi}\left(\vec{r}\right)\equiv\vec{r}-\vec{u}\left(\vec{\phi}\right)$, and following some elastic approximations. But I believe the derivation is not transparent (for e.g. A5 should be an approximation, not an exact result).

I was wondering whether there is an easier way to arrive at this result without defining this spurious field $\vec{\phi}$. If not, I will very much appreciate it if there is a clear way to think through this derivarion.